# Probability of being back at the origin

Tags: probability

I toss $a$ fair coins and move right one each time I get a head. I then toss $b$ fair coins and move left one each time I get a head.

What is the probability I am back at the origin?

I tried to work it out and ended up with ${a+b \choose a}/2^{a+b}$ but I am not at all sure I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are successful iff in both stages you throw the same number $k$ of heads. If $a\geq b$ this can be any number in the range $[0\>..\>b]$. Therefore the probability you are after amounts to
$$p={1\over 2^{a+b}}\sum_{k=0}^b{a\choose k}{b\choose k}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

The probability of going $n$ times right and then $n$ times left is just the product
$$
{a\choose n}\left({1\over2}\right)^a{b\choose n}\left({1\over2}\right)^b=
{a\choose n}{b\choose n}\left({1\over2}\right)^{a+b}.
$$
Of course you have to sum this over all possible $n$, that is for $0\le n\le\min(a,b)$. By using Vandermonde summation formula, if $a\le b$ one gets:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{a}{a\choose n}{b\choose n}=
\sum_{n=0}^{a}{a\choose n}{b\choose b-n}={a+b\choose b}
$$
while the result is ${a+b\choose a}$ if $a\ge b$. In the end, your probability is then
$$
{a+b\choose \max(a,b)}\left({1\over2}\right)^{a+b}.
$$

Comment: Note that the final binomial coefficient takes only two possible values, which are really the same value :).

Comment: @ErickWong Oh, right! I hadn't noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are correct, but I wanted to provide a direct combinatorial proof for your original correct answer. $(2)^{(a+b)}$ is the total number of possible outcomes of all the flips, so we want to show that $a+b\choose a$ is the total number of flips that result in you returning successfully.

Assume, wlog, that a is the lesser number. Well, each successful return corresponds to a certain number of the $b$ flips being heads. Thus, pick at most $a$ of those flips -- it can never be more than $a$, since otherwise even if every one of the $a$ leftward flips was heads, the rightward flips would take you back too far. Suppose that we have $n$ heads out of all the $b$ potentially-leftward flips. Thus, of the $a$ potentially-rightward flips, $n$ of them must be heads. But instead of directly specifying those, let us specify the $a-n$ that are not heads.

What this shows is that every successful set of coin flips can be described by describing $n$ flips out of the $b$ and $a-n$ out of the $a$ for some $a \leq n$. Therefore, it is equivalent to specifying $a$ flips out of $a+b$.